# Optimize finding the Nth occurrence of character in string

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a sql server function which returns substring before the Nth occurence of character.

For example,
`SELECT dbo.fn_getFirstNthSentence('.', 'hello world.It.is.raining.today', 3)`
returns 'hello world.It.Is.' as a result.

The function I wrote looks dirty and slow so I want to optimize it.
Any advice to make it clean is appreciated.

Thank you.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getFirstNthSentence
(
  @TargetStr VARCHAR(MAX) ,
  @SearchedStr VARCHAR(8000) ,
  @Occurrence INT
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @pos INT ,
        @counter INT ,
        @ret INT;

    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr);

    IF ( @pos = 0 )
        RETURN @SearchedStr

    SET @counter = 1;

    IF @Occurrence = 1
        SET @ret = @pos;

    ELSE
        BEGIN

            WHILE ( @counter < @Occurrence )
                BEGIN

                    IF(LEN(@SearchedStr) < @pos + 1)
                        RETURN @SearchedStr

                    SELECT  @ret = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr,
                                             @pos + 1);
                    IF(@ret = 0)
                        RETURN @SearchedStr
                    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
                    SET @pos = @ret;
                END;
        END;
    RETURN LEFT(@SearchedStr, @ret)
END;
```

Comment: If your code runs without error, then kudos on you, but you might want to post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: SQL Server is really good at handling data but it is not good at string manipulation. You could make this faster using t-sql but I don't think any sql will be faster at this type of thing than CLR.

Comment: someone might have a regular expression

Comment: @AndrewDeighton sql server does not support regular expressions. It can handle some rudimentary pattern matching but not full blown regex.

Comment: So do you always want the left portion of the source value up to and including the nth instance of a single character?

Comment: @SeanLange correct.

Comment: I asked about single character because in your function you pass in a varchar(max) but the value is '.' If a single character is ok I have a must faster solution for you.

Comment: @SeanLange that varchar(max) must be my mistake. it supposed to be a single character :)

Comment: @SeanLange 99% of the time, TargetStr will be a period('.').

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to solve some other problem (denormalized data maybe?) and think that text parsing is the solution. SQL Server provides full text search capabilities and indexing with functions like CONTAINS and FREETEXT but that won't make handling denormalized data easier. If you *do* have denormalize data, normalize it. If you know that you want to search for the 5th entry in an "array", you can easily extract these values to a separate table

Comment: One option to avoid denormalization (except actually using a separate table) is to use sparse columns with one column for each possible "field". This makes the use of "key-value" tables obsolete. A table can have thousands of sparse columns but only stores those that actually have data

Comment: Another option is to use an xml-typed field and [XML indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx) to speed up xml queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is yet another option using a delimited string splitter. The XML method already posted is a good one but this approach does not require a table variable.

This is created as an inline table valued function which should keep the performance really fast.

```
create function fn_getFirstNthSentence
(
    @SearchedStr varchar(100)
    , @Occurrence int
    , @Delimiter char(1)
) returns table as return

    with ParsedValues as
    (
        select Item
            , ItemNumber
        from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@SearchedStr, @Delimiter)
        where ItemNumber <= @Occurrence
    )

    select top 1 ResultString = STUFF(
    (
        select @Delimiter + Item
        from ParsedValues
        order by ItemNumber
        for xml path('')), 1,1, '') + @Delimiter
    from ParsedValues
```

This is also using a splitter created by Jeff Moden. It has one feature that none of the other splitter have...a column to indicate which position the value came from. You can find his article an ensuing discussion here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Then if you want to execute it you can do this quite simply.

```
declare @String varchar(100) = 'hello world.It.is.raining.today.'
    , @Num int = 3
    , @Delimiter char(1) = '.'
;

select *
from fn_getFirstNthSentence(@String, @Num, @Delimiter)
```

If you don't like Jeff Moden's splitter you can find several other options here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings I don't use Moden's for everything but when you need to keep the parsed values in order it is awesome.

--EDIT--

Here is how you could modify this to become a scalar function instead of an inline table valued function. My preference would be to keep the itvf as they are faster and more flexible.

```
create function fn_getFirstNthSentenceScalar
(
    @SearchedStr varchar(100) = 'hello world.It.is.raining.today.this is after 5'
    , @Occurrence int = 5
    , @Delimiter char(1) = '.'
) returns varchar(max) as begin

    declare @RetVal varchar(max);

    with ParsedValues as
    (
        select Item
            , ItemNumber
        from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@SearchedStr, @Delimiter)
        where ItemNumber <= @Occurrence
    )

    select top 1 @RetVal = STUFF(
    (
        select @Delimiter + Item
        from ParsedValues
        order by ItemNumber
        for xml path('')), 1,1, '') + @Delimiter
    from ParsedValues;

    return @RetVal
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to return as varchar not as table?

Comment: The reason I used an inline table valued function is because they are WAY faster than a scalar function. You could change this to return a scalar value but you will be sacrificing performance and flexibility.

Comment: I see thank you. I was hoping if there was a faster way using a scalar function. But thank you very much! Great help

Comment: @jkl the fastest way would be to normalize your data, use sparse columns or xml field with XML indexes. Anything that avoids reading and parsing all data. It depends on what your *actual* problem is though

Answer (score 1):

--I find these functions to be a mine-field, and at the risk of stepping on a mine I've tried some simplifications - maybe a microscopic improvement in performance

```
alter FUNCTION fn_getFirstNthSentence
(
@TargetStr VARCHAR(MAX) ,
@SearchedStr VARCHAR(8000) ,
@Occurrence INT
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @pos INT ,
    @counter INT ;

IF @Occurrence < 1  
    RETURN NULL;

SELECT @counter = 0, @POS = 1;

WHILE (@counter < @Occurrence AND @POS > 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT  @POS = CHARINDEX(@TargetStr, @SearchedStr,
                                @pos + 1);
    IF @POS > 0 
        SET  @counter = @counter + 1;

END;
RETURN CASE WHEN @POS > 0 THEN
            LEFT(@SearchedStr, @POS)
        ELSE
            @SearchedStr
        END;

END;
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems more simple, clean and faster!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is via XML

I can't see your benchmarks, but it is certainly far less code.  An added option could be Find the 3rd through 5th occurrence by adding a parameter and changing the  **Where Seq<=@FindPos** to **Where Seq Between range1 and range2**.

```
Declare @FindPos int = 3
Declare @String  varchar(max) = 'hello world.It.is.raining.today'
Declare @Delim   varchar(10)  = '.'


Declare @XML xml,@RetVal varchar(max) = ''
Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delim,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)

Declare @Table table (Seq int identity(1,1),String varchar(max))
Insert Into @Table Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)')))+@Delim as value FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)

Select @RetVal=@RetVal + String from @Table Where Seq<=@FindPos Order By Seq

Select @RetVal
```

Returns

```
hello world.It.is.
```

> **EDIT:** If it helps, below is my generic parsing function which returns a
>   normalized table...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('hello world. It. is. . raining.today','.')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select Key_Value = ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

So for example:

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('hello world.It.is.raining.today','.')
```

Returns

```
Key_PS  Key_Value
1       hello world
2       It
3       is
4       raining
5       today
```

Comment: Thank you. This is something i couldn't think of.

Comment: No string parsing optimization is going to fix performance. The database will still have to read *all* rows and parse each individual value. This question probably hides a different problem, like denormalization. The only way to fix this is to fix the *original* problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 100% agreement.  Somebody should do an analysis on how many questions there are on SO for parsing strings.

Comment: It's all of them +1000 - SQL Server 2016 adds a STRING_SPLIT TVF that is about as fast as the fastest custom solution - using a SQLCLR function.