# Alternative for INSTR() in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an alternative for the `INSTR()` function used in Oracle for SQL Server.

I need to use `INSTR()` with all four parameters,

```
INSTR(string, substring [, start_position [, nth_appearance ]])
```

SQL Server has an option for `CHARINDEX()`, but it does not allow me to mention the 'nth appearance', it only takes 3 parameters

```
CHARINDEX(substring, string, start)
```

Is there any way I can get the exact functionality as `INSTR()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server - find nth occurrence in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726111/sql-server-find-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimize finding the Nth occurrence of character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659811/optimize-finding-the-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-string)

Comment: You can create your own function - https://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/instr#:~:text=In%20Oracle%2C%20INSTR%20function%20returns,use%20a%20user%2Ddefined%20function.

Comment: It would be useful to give an example of the input and output you want, for those not familiar with the exact functionality of Oracle.

Comment: I can work this out if no other option is left. The thing is I am running a kind of for loop .. and in the nth appearance section I want to get the value (for eg @i value which will increment each time the block of code executes). This can be the possible solution though! .. to create a different function!

Comment: That function in that link would be terrible for performance mind, @AnkitBajpai . I don't recommend it's use.